# How to find and replace sentences using substitute in vim?

Tags: vim

I am trying to rewrite all instances of `\sigma \circ \tau` as `\tau \circ \sigma` in the text that follows. I have tried to use

`:%s/\sigma \circ \tau/\tau \circ \sigma`

There is no example of such a transformation (involving several words) on the vim tips wiki (I could be mistaken). See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace).

```
    1 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 9 \\
    9 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 1 \\
    \vspace{1cm} \\
    2 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 7 \\
    7 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 6 \\
    6 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 3 \\
    3 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 2 \\
    \vspace{1cm} \\
    8 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 5 \\
    5 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 4 \\
    4 &\temp{\sigma \circ \tau} 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because backslashes have a special meaning in vim regex. For example, `\s` means *a whitespace character*, `\c` tells vim to search case insensitive, and `\t` searches for a tab.

To search for a literal backslash character, you must escape it with another backslash, i.e.

```
:%s/\\sigma \\circ \\tau/\\tau \\circ \\sigma
```

If you'd like to make your regular expression shorter, you could do:

```
:%s/\v(\\sigma) (\\circ) (\\tau)/\3 \2 \1
```

or

```
:%s/\v(\\sigma)( \\circ )(\\tau)/\3\2\1
```

instead. I also highly recommend reading through [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com), which gives a nice overview of how to use regex in vim.